# Accessing mySQL on WAMP from Android

Tags: java, php, android, webserver, wamp

I am having trouble understanding how exactly to configure WAMP for remote (not LAN) access by  an Android app to the SQL database that I have created with it.
I understand that I shouldn't be directly connecting to the database from the app but use a PHP script to query the database and return the results.
What I am not understanding is how all this fits together, Where do I put the PHP scripts, How do I access them, How do I allow and connect to the webserver to get the data out of the database.

I have followed and searched for lots of tutorials on this but they all seem to deal with only using wamp in localhost, I can successfully access the data locally but I am stumped with how to set all that up so that I could query the database from any internet connection on my android device.

Any advice on how to achieve this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: If you have a static ip at home you can open a port in your firewall and then use your public ip address to access the site.  Or, the better option, buy a domain and pay for webhosting and put your php code on the server of the hosting company. I.e. search "php hosting"

Comment: @developerwjk Thank you for commenting, asking on here really was the last resort so I glad of the help. I already have a domain but I am using free hosting (000webhost) does this matter? I know I should know more but tutorials on this are sparse at least with what I have been able to find on google or they leave out the details such as webhosting and port forwarding. If you could spare some of your time I would really appreciate a "noob" step by step guide on setting it all up from database to webhost to android. That really would "make my day".

Comment: Free hosting usually appends advertisements server-side to your HTML output, which can screw things up if your Android code is looking for a particular response and there's all this extra stuff for ads in the response.

Comment: @developerwjk Ok, are you able to recommend a good not to expensive host? Also would you put an answer on here for this which would include a "do this first then do that then that etc etc" I'm not asking for code but rather directions... Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You have to upload your php script to your server :

Ex : Your php is in : myserver.com/myscript.php

In your Android app, You post your variables, and you connect your php script with HttpClient :

```
    URL_TO_YOUR_SCRIPT = "myserver.com/myscript.php";
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userId", userId));

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    // specify the URL you want to post to
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL_TO_YOUR_SCRIPT);
    try {
        // create a list to store HTTP variables and their values
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "UTF-8"));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            HttpEntity getResponseEntity = response.getEntity();
            return getResponseEntity.getContent();

        } else {
            Log.e("ERROR", statusLine.getStatusCode() + "");
            HttpEntity getResponseEntity = response.getEntity();
            return getResponseEntity.getContent();
        }

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

In your php :

```
<?
    $userId=$_REQUEST['userId'];
    ....
   // in general you return a json string to get status and result
?>
```